# Access/Index Array In Simulink

Tags: simulink

I have a 2D matrix/array in my model, as shown in image. I need to be able to index/access it randomly and pass it as a signal. How do I do this?

I can't use From File block, because the storage is forced to be double and too large for my embedded design.

It doesn't appear I can use From Workspace block...because this array is defined in my model as SoundArray.

This seem like it should be SO SIMPLE, but I just can’t figure it out. The only way I can think of doing it is in custom C code…which I don’t want to do.

Thanks

[Array Definition and Model At Bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRVZu.png)

Answer (score 0):

A matlab Function block (formerly EML-block) can pick up model workspace data if it is in "Parameter" **scope** and you define a Parameter input in the Function block. You could then use other inputs for controlling the random access, then return the desired position as a signal output from the Matlab function block.

```
function y = fcn(i,j,soundArray)
y = soundArray(i,j);
```

(Where soundArray is defined as a Parameter, and i and j are Inputs)

Edit: 
Or define a Data Store Memory (add definition block). Then put a Data Store Read block for that memory which is routed to a selector block with 2 dimensions and "starting index (port)" for both those dimensions. 
I believe you can use Model Workspace data to initialize the Data Store Memory, but I don't think that Model Workspace data is "live" during simulation.

Comment: My issue with this is, SoundArray is a variable…not a const.
Matlab:
“Parameter”
“Constant whose value is defined in the MATLAB® workspace, or derived from a Simulink® block parameter that you define and initialize in the parent masked subsystem. The Stateflow data object must have the same name as the parameter.”

Comment: So for my understanding; is the SoundArray also a variable in the Simulink context? I.e. does it change during simulink execution. If not I think the Parameter solution works. Otherwise I suspect a Data Store is the way to go, but it would have to be intitialized first.

Comment: SoundArray[n 2] matrix/variable is defined in Simulink (as shown above) but initialized with pread() in custom C code from a file. I do want the ability to change SoundArray. This all will run on Linux, which introduces issues with the blocks I can use and data types. I have never used a Data Store let alone initialized one from custom code.

Comment: What is surprising, something so simple is turning out so difficult.

Comment: I ended up reading the file in once with fread() custom C code...populating SoundArray then using temporal logic (after(100, msec) ) to copy frames of SoundArray into a temporary buffer that is an output of the Stateflow chart. This output can then be used by the rest of the model....This is the main copy part...still in C...but in Stateflow...memcpy(SoundOut4410, &SoundArray[RandLocation][0], FRAME_SIZE );//This seems like a Mickey Mouse way to have to do things

Comment: I really think you would save yourself some pain using a Data Store with storage class int16 and initialize it to the SoundArray. Is it your memory constraints that prevent you from doing so? I'm actually surprised you managed to tap into data in the model WS in such a manner...but if it works...   The datastore can be initialized with a script if you could run this as initialization. (e.g. function d=loadSA(); fid=fopen('SAFile.xx','r'); d=fread(fid,[2 25000000],'int16');fclose(fid)). (Given that matrix format is compatible with matlab fread, but a ' should be able to fix).